# Appending grandtotal and subtotal rows to two-level row and column index dataframe

Tags: database, pandas, sum, concatenation, multi-index

```
import pandas, io

data = io.StringIO('''Fruit,Color,Count,Price
Apple,Red,3,1.29
Apple,Green,9,0.99
Pear,Red,25,2.59
Pear,Green,26,2.79
Lime,Green,99,0.39
''')
df_unindexed = pandas.read_csv(data)
df = df_unindexed.set_index(['Fruit', 'Color'])
grandtotal=df.sum().to_frame().T
subtotal=df.sum(axis=0,level=[0])

df
Out[830]: 
             Count  Price
Fruit Color              
Apple Red        3   1.29
      Green      9   0.99
Pear  Red       25   2.59
      Green     26   2.79
Lime  Green     99   0.39

grandtotal
Out[831]: 
   Count  Price
0  162.0   8.05

subtotal
Out[832]: 
       Count  Price
Fruit              
Apple     12   2.28
Lime      99   0.39
Pear      51   5.38
```

1) How would I append the grand total as the top row (keeping the original dataframe format)

1a) Also I want to move the row indices to the top row so that I can use those cells for ('All Fruits','Total')

2) How would I append the subtotal on top of each fruit?

2a) I have subtotal row with two indices

Desired output:

```
Fruit   Color   Count   Price
All Fruits  Total   162 8.05
Apple   Subtotal    12  2.28
Apple   Red 3   1.29
Apple   Green   9   0.99
Peer    Subtotal    51  5.38
Pear    Red 25  2.59
Pear    Green   26  2.79
Lime    Subtotal    99  0.39
Lime    Green   99  0.39
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.concat`, `assign`, `sum`, and `set_index`:

```
df_out = pd.concat([df,
                    df.sum(level=0).assign(Color='SubTotal')\
                      .set_index('Color', append=True),
                    df.sum().to_frame().T\
                      .assign(Fruit='All Fruit', 
                              Color='Total')\
                      .set_index(['Fruit', 'Color'])])\
           .sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                   Count  Price
Fruit     Color                 
All Fruit Total     162.0   8.05
Apple     Green       9.0   0.99
          Red         3.0   1.29
          SubTotal   12.0   2.28
Lime      Green      99.0   0.39
          SubTotal   99.0   0.39
Pear      Green      26.0   2.79
          Red        25.0   2.59
          SubTotal   51.0   5.38
```

Comment: This is perfect. I had to readjust the subtotal and grandtotal rows bit differently.

Comment: I am glad it helped.  Happy coding!

Comment: Could you recommend any videos/ material for multi-index operations? Any good pandas tutorials?

Comment: Actually, pandas documentation is pretty good on this. Other than that, I do most of my learning on here, Stack Overflow.  Asking questions getting some help from people much much smarter than I and also, answering questions is a great way to learn Pandas.

Comment: Sorry to bother but how do you know to answer a question? Do you sign up for that separately on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Oh no.... You can answer any question on stack overflow right now. http://www.wikihow.com/Answer-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow